# Is it possible to reprogram wireless mouse receiver to receive signals from different mouse?

Tags: wireless-mouse

I have a Tecknet wireless Mouse which has a USB receiver. The exact make and model is: TeckNet M002 2.4G Classic Wireless Mouse - 4800 DPI -6 Adjustment Levels - Nano USB wireless receiver.

In fact I have two of these, but I have lost the mouse for one and the receiver for the other. So my question, is there a way to reprogram the mouse receiver to receive signals from the other mouse?

Comment: To me it is odd that it wouldn't already do so. Weird thing to try: Remove the batteries , unplug the dongle , wait 20 seconds, plug it all back in, hope.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. I don't know much about it but i assume they are set or different frequencies of something. Perhaps there is a way to sync them

Answer (score 2):

It's possible even in case of no Reconnect button. 
Link below describes the process. In brief, just plug receiver in, put the mouse near the receiver, switch the mouse on and press any button. It will reconnect in 15 seconds.

http://www.tecknetonline.com/download/User_Manual/M002_User_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

All the wireless peripherals I know of, including mice, have a button called "reset" or "connect" or something to that effect.

The mouse and the receiver are paired to each other from the factory, but that pairing might get lost due to battery loss or whatever. This is when the "connect" function would be useful. A mouse and/or a receiver wouldn't know that you're now wanting to connect a different but identical mouse, so that should work exactly as good.

If your mouse or receiver doesn't have a button on it (typically on the underside, or under the battery lid) then you're out of luck.